# Dropzone.js multiple image upload not working properly

Tags: laravel, dropzone.js, multiple-file-upload

Jquery

```
Dropzone.options.sliderDropzone = {
autoProcessQueue: true,
parallelUploads: 1,
acceptedFiles : 'image/*',
paramName : "resim",
init: function () {
        this.on("complete", function (file) {
            if (this.getUploadingFiles().length === 0 && this.getQueuedFiles().length === 0) {
                setTimeout(function(){ location.reload(true); }, 2000);

            }



        })
    }
};
```

Html

```
<form action="/upload" class="dropzone dropzone-file-area " id="sliderDropzone" method="POST" >

                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="dz-default dz-message"><span><i class="icon-cloud-download" style="font-size:50px;display:block"></i><br/> Resmi sürükleyip bırakın veya buraya tıklayın.</span></div>


            </form>
```

Server Side Laravel

```
public function resim_upload(Request $request,$proje_id)
{


    if($resim = $request->file("resim"))
    {

            $time = time();
            $resim_isim = $time.".jpg";
            $resim_isim_thumb = "galeri_thumb_".$time.".jpg";
            $resim_isim_large = "galeri_large_".$time.".jpg";
            Image::make($resim->getRealPath())->fit(600,400)->save(public_path("uploads/".$resim_isim_thumb));
            Image::make($resim->getRealPath())->resize(null, 720, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            })->save(public_path("uploads/".$resim_isim_large));

            $input = [];
            $input["isim"] = $resim_isim;
            $input["imageable_id"] = $proje_id;
            $input["imageable_type"] ="App\Proje";

            $input["sira"] = 0;
            Resim::create($input);



        Session::flash("b_durum",0);
        Session::flash("bilgilendirme","Resim başarıyla yüklendi");




    }
}
```

Problem occurs when upload more than one files. For example i wanna upload 5 image files. On database side 5 records added but some image names are same. When i controlled the upload folder 3 image uploaded but image records on database are 5.

image names in upload folder are

```
galeri_large_1479329550.jpg
galeri_large_1479345567.jpg
galeri_large_1479374665.jpg
```

database records

```
image name column 
---------------------------
galeri_large_1479329550.jpg
galeri_large_1479329550.jpg
galeri_large_1479345567.jpg
galeri_large_1479345567.jpg
galeri_large_1479374665.jpg
```

Sometimes there is no problem when upload multiple files but generally this problem occurs. So i can't understand why problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($request->file("resim") as $thumbsnail) {
                $thu = time().'.'.$thumbsnail->getClientOriginalExtension();
                Image::make($thumbsnail->getRealPath())->resize(600, 400, function ($constraint) {
                    $constraint->aspectRatio();
                })->save($destinationPath.'/'.$thu);

//Insert to the DB


            }
//Then return response
```

Comment: parallelUploads : 1 in dropzone config. So uploads not array. So this is not solution.

Comment: Ok. My mistake. I taught they all have the same name

Answer (score 0):

I found this code in the library:

```
key: "_getParamName",
    value: function _getParamName(n) {
      if (typeof this.options.paramName === "function") {
        return this.options.paramName(n);
      } else {
        return "" + this.options.paramName + (this.options.uploadMultiple ? "[" + n + "]" : "");
      }
    }
```

And wrote by:

```
key: "_getParamName",
    value: function _getParamName(n) {
      if (typeof this.options.paramName === "function") {
        return this.options.paramName(n);
      } else {
        return "" + this.options.paramName;
      }
    }
```

This worked for me!